# why I must restart playframework after I update routes or any static file

Tags: playframework

I encountered a strange problem, after I update the file routes or any static file, I must stop the play, then run , play run my project name, my changes take effect, does anyone know the reason?

thanks

Comment: I have never had this happen...can you provide more detail?

Comment: What is the framework version? Is this behavior reproducible in a new and empty play project?

Comment: From my experience, running the app in dev mode, the only scenario where I'm forced to restart the app is when I change the port number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command with ~ as prefix for enabling auto reloading.
**play ~run**  in windows command prompt or 
**~run** in play console