# Scala Play Framework application doesn't restart properly after changing sources

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.2 application written in Scala that starts and runs properly (using `play run`). Recently, however, it began to have trouble *restarting* correctly after discovering source file changes.

The application used to rebuild and restart automatically when it detected changes to source files. Play still detects source changes and *attempts* to restart the server, however it only makes it as far as stopping it - it's not restarted correctly.

Here's what `play run` looks like in the console:

```
[info] Loading project definition from <path>
[info] Set current project to GTF (in build file:<path>)

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
[info] application - START
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

So far, so good. The application is started and running properly at this point. However, if I change a source file and refresh the page, the following shows up in the console:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to <path>...

--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] application - STOP
[info] play - Shutdown application default Akka system.
```

And that's it. It seems to compile/build, but it never gets to `application - START`. The browser window just sits there perpetually loading the page.

I have tried `play clean` and `play clean-all`, but that didn't solve the problem. I've also tried running the application with a tilda, like so: `play ~run` ([this was suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599946/why-i-must-restart-playframework-after-i-update-routes-or-any-static-file)), but that didn't work either. Any ideas? Again, it's very puzzling because it *used* to work properly. This issue makes development rather annoying, since I have to restart the server manually each time I change any source file. Thanks.

Comment: I assume it's your code that's logging START/STOP.  Instead of logging STOP, try new Exception().printStackTrace().  This will dump the current thread stack, this may shed more light.  Anyway, I suspect something is calling System.exit, maybe Akka (it likes to do this when it catches exceptions).  Could be a classloading issue.  Check logs/application.log to see if that sheds more light on the issue.

Comment: I think you're right... it has something to do with Akka, since eliminating my `Akka.system.scheduler.schedule` calls on startup eliminates the problem. It's still odd that it starts properly in the first place though. I wasn't able to get anything particularly useful from the stack trace... and nothing in the logs either. I'll keep hacking at it, thanks.

Comment: You could try setting a break point in java.lang.System.exit to see what's calling it.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't you be using "play ~run"?  The Play application shouldn't need to restart to compile and apply your changes.

Comment: I think you missed the part in my question where I say: "I've also tried running the application with a tilda, like so: `play ~run`, but that didn't work either."